# Angular ng-disabled

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If someone have this problem please answer me.

Something like this works fine (element will be disabled when its true):

```
            <input type="text" class="no-phone-input" name="phone" ng-model="currentOrder.Customer.Phone" ng-pattern="/^[0-9-]+$/" ng-disabled="{{currentOrder.Status == 7 || currentOrder.Status == 9}}"/>
```

And this works too:

```
<input type="text" id="orderNumberInput" class="no-num-input" name="OrderNumber" ng-model ="currentOrder.OrderNumber" ng-disabled="{{currentOrder.Status == 2 || currentOrder.Status == 3  || currentOrder.Status == 4 || currentOrder.Status == 6 || currentOrder.Status == 7 || currentOrder.Status == 8 || currentOrder.Status == 9}}" required/>
```

But this doesn`t work at the same angular view (same scope):

```
<input id="customer" name="customer" type="text" ng-model="currentOrder.Customer.Name" ng-disabled="{{currentOrder.Status == 7 || currentOrder.Status == 9}}" required/>
```

Element doesn`t disabled...

Comment: ng-disabled="{currentOrder.Status == 7 || currentOrder.Status == 9}" . single brackets or no brackets .. ? isnt this an expression ?

Comment: {}, (), no brackets - same result. Doesn`t work on customer input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or just do in controller:

```
$scope.disabler = function(){
    if($scope.currentOrder.Status ==7 || $scope.currentOrder.Status ==9 ){
        return true;
    }
}
```

and in your template :

```
<input id="customer" name="customer" type="text" ng-model="currentOrder.Customer.Name" ng-disabled="disabler()" required/>
```

Comment: thx. Works. But I am still confused.. don`t know why sometimes it doesn`t work

Comment: well to me your solution also looks fine. I haven't tried it though

Comment: I don`t know what happen, my solution works fine but on one input it haven`t worked at all. Some kinde of magic.

Answer (score 0):

this works in my build ..

```
<input id="customer" name="customer" type="text" ng-model="currentOrder.Customer.Name" ng-disabled="(currentOrder.Status == 7 || currentOrder.Status == 9)" required/>
```

change `{{}}` into `()`